# CSS Image Gallery will not center

Tags: css, center

```
    .imgContain{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.imgContain img{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
}

.imgContain img:hover{
    opacity: 0.60;
}
```

For some reason, this will not center on my page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide link or also provide html. // EDIT: Actually, from just the CSS I can tell it's because the image is floated left...unless you are only trying to center the container, in which case, its width is 100%, so it can't quite be centered.

Comment: It was the float:left!! Thanks

Comment: Agree with @thesublimeobject. The container takes up 100% width but the image is set at float: left, which looks like the cause.

Comment: If the width of the container is set to 100%, it takes up the width of the entire window or its parent container. You cannot center it if it takes up the entire width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to understand what you really want to happen, but here is another way using `inline-block` - http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/29jvS/

### HTML

```
<div class="imgContain">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.imgContain{
    text-align: center;
}

.imgContain img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please specify the width for your image container in terms of pixels. when you give the width as 100% `margin: 0 auto;` will not work. please check this fiddle and let me know if this solved your problem :
http://jsfiddle.net/LynDL/2/

Comment: just a small edit please add `margin: 0 auto;` to your `.imgContain img` as well... here's the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/LynDL/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of the imgContain width. Its in '%' while the image widths you provided in 'px'. Suppose if you want 4 250px images in row then you should keep the imgContain width 1000px. eg :

```
.imgContain{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.imgContain img{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
}
```

If you want to go fluid way then let the imgContain width be 100% but change the image widths to 25%.

```
.imgContain{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.imgContain img{
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

Hope it helps.